# Is old Hard-disk have anything usable for me ? (Anything at-least)

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

MY hard-disk was stop working at last saturday https://superuser.com/questions/600288/seagate-500-hb-hardisk-internal-hard-driver-failed-to-work-now-what-i-do

I lost the data.
it's out of Warranty.

The product is Barracuda 500 GB HDD come with 1 Year warranty. Warranty is lost. Now Can I recover the data.

Is this have any value or just goes useless for me.

I have got new HDD. Now what should I do of old hard-disk. Can I got my DATA back if I do something.

Any help !

Comment: Please don't repeat the same question. What you want to do with a broken hard drive is *entirely* up to you. We have plenty of questions about data recovery already if you want to go that route.

Comment: I don't think your question is whether the old disk does have any value, but 'How can I recover my data from my old disk?'. If so, please edit your question. And whatever you do from now on MAKE BACKUPS!!!

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can check to see if you can get data back:

- Connect the HDD directly to the motherboard (using IDE / SATA cable) and check if the motherboard BIOS is still able to see it. If you can still see the HDD on the motherboard BIOS there is a possibility you can still do some recovery (by yourself before going to some professional data recovery). If you can't see the HDD on the motherboard, your best bet is to contact some professional data recovery and pay them.
- Assuming you can still see the HDD on the motherboard BIOS (and the HDD is not making any noise preferably), boot using a Linux LiveCD and try accessing your HDD using the liveCD.

If your HDD is still on decent condition you MAY be able to copy data out of the HDD into another USB / external HDD / other internally connected HDD that your LiveCD can access.

You can also use a program called [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com) to check your HDD data as lots of people have claimed that it does some strange things that somehow can make the HDD readable again, but again, the assumption is that there is no physical damage to the HDD. I guess the good thing about SpinRite is they have [30 days money back warranty](https://www.grc.com/cs/licenseinfo.htm). If you buy it, try it, its not doing anything for you, go and return it within the 30 days.

Disclaimer: I'm not a seller for SpinRite nor affiliated with GRC at all, but I do have heard a lot of his podcast (security now) and heard so much good things about it. I did use it myself and have managed to recover data. My experience was: before spinrite, I can't copy anything. After spinrite, I can copy the data out. So as far as I'm concerned it does works on some condition.

If all fail, or the HDD is making clicking noise, you may need to go to professional data recovery people and pay them.

Also if you don't care about the data (or you already got your data back), fun thing to do with your dead HDD - open it up, and grab the strong magnet inside. Those are extremely strong magnet, and fun. Note: It can also easily clip your fingers together with a fair bit of strength and can hurt. But fun.

Good luck getting your data back.

Comment: Spinrite doesn't do 'strange things' ;-), it just goes underneath the file system and works on as low a level as possible. If there are still recognizable sectors, it will read all sectors. If it encounters a bad one, it will have the heads approach the bad sector from multiple angles, using the tiny variations in head alignment to reread/reread/reread the sector. HD sectors are large, so much of the data of the sector will still be recoverable. The damaged bytes SR tries to reconstruct by analyzing its read results statistically. Therefore SR operation can take from hours to months.